# Animation is not working as expected in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 rows that have different contents, columns, and components inside. When I click the item in the same row state is getting changed and second row is appearing where I can click close and 2nd row will disappear and first one will be visible again. It looks like kind of slider but not for images. I applied the following animation but it doesn't work as expected:

```
      <transition :name="isBack ? 'slideback' : 'slide'">
        <div v-if="row === 1" class="columns">
    ...
        </div>
      </transition>
          <transition :name="isBack ? 'slideback' : 'slide'">
        <div v-if="row === 2" class="columns">
    ...
        </div>
      </transition>

selectProduct(item) {
      this.itemSelected = item
      this.isBack = false
      this.row = 2
    },
    close() {
      this.isBack = true
      this.row = 1
    },
```

The issue is that it works correctly only first time. When second time you click another item in the first step it starts always sliding back instead of sliding. The goal is whenever you click any item in the first row it should slide and when you click close in the second row it should slide back. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: After first time, your `isBack` is always `false` and your `row` is always `2` unless you click close right? That is the issue.

Comment: Yes. @MatJ also there is another issue 2nd row is comming from the bottom left and then moves to top when 2nd row is not visible anymore.